# CakePHP 3.x Passing Route GET Parameter Name to Controller

Tags: php, cakephp, controller, routes, cakephp-3.0

I am trying to access a GET variable that is defined in `config/routes.php`using the name of the placeholder in the route.

In the below example, I am attempting to set `:school_id` = to `$id` in the controller.

**Routes code `config/routes.php`:**

```
Router::connect('/schools/:school_id/students', [
    'controller' => 'Schools',
    'action'=> 'index'
]);
```

**Controller code `src/Controller/SchoolsController.php`:**

```
public function index(){
        $id = $this->request->params['pass']['school_id'];
};
```

In this case `$this->request->params['pass']['school_id'];` is not set. The `:school_id` value does show up if I instead write `$this->request->params['pass'][0];`.

Is there a way to access the url value that is supposed to be in the spot of `:school_id` using it's name rather than `0`? In other words, can I reference it using the named key that I defined in the routes.php file?

Answer (score 1):

You can get the parameters using this syntax.

```
$this->request->getParam();
```

Comment: I have tried `$this->request->param('school_id')` and it does not return anything. When I try `getParam()` it says the method does not exist. I'm on Cake version 3.3.15.